# Targeting certain @media size and device-pixel of 1

Tags: css

Can I target a certain `@media` size that is only targeted for standard monitors (not device pixels of 2 or more, e.g. tablets)?

I want to target between 1000px and 1040px *only* for monitors with device-pixel of 1.

I have tried the following, but when done live it changes to @media not all

```
@media (max-width: 1017px) and (min-width: 1001px) and (max-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have skipped the selector:

```
@media (max-width: 1017px) and (min-width: 1001px) and (max-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {
  div {
    display: block;
  }
}
```